# Regular Expression - Capture and Replace Select Sequences

Tags: regex, sed

Take the following file...

```
ABCD,1234,http://example.com/mpe.exthttp://example/xyz.ext
EFGH,5678,http://example.com/wer.exthttp://example/ljn.ext
```

Note that "ext" is a constant file extension throughout the file.

I am looking for an expression to turn that file into something like this...

```
ABCD,1234,http://example.com/mpe.ext
ABCD,1234,http://example/xyz.ext
EFGH,5678,http://example.com/wer.ext
EFGH,5678,http://example/ljn.ext
```

In a nutshell I need to capture everything up to the urls. Then I need to capture each URL and put them on their own line with the leading capture.

I am working with sed to do this and I cannot figure out how to make it work correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be sed? A tool that supports more than POSIX/GNU Basic Regular Expressions could do this very easily.

Answer (score 6):

If the number of URLs in each line is guaranteed to be two, you can use:

```
sed -r "s/([A-Z0-9,]{10})(.+\.ext)(.+\.ext)/\1\2\n\1\3/" < input
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not require the first two fields to be a particular width or limit the set of (non-comma) characters between the commas. Instead, it keys on the commas themselves.

```
sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{2\}\)\(.*\.ext\)\(http:.*\)/\1\3\n\1\4/' inputfile.txt
```

You could change the "2" to match any number of comma-delimited fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have no sed available to me at the moment.

Wouldn't

```
sed -r 's/(....),(....),(.*\.ext)(http.*\.ext)/\1,\2,\3\n\1,\2,\4/g'
```

do the trick?

**Edit**: *removed the lazy quantifier*

Comment: Very good idea (I hope the part before the URLs is that constant). But I thought that sed doesn't support lazy quantifiers.